# If $f$ and $g$ are two disjoint permutations in group of permutation on $n$ symbols such that $(fg)^n=e$ for some $n$,then $f^n=e$ and $g^n=e$.

Tags: group-theory

> If $f$ and $g$ are two disjoint permutations in group of permutation on $n$ symbols such that $(fg)^n=e$ for some $n$,then $f^n=e$ and $g^n=e$.

It's easy to verify through examples, but I'm not able to construct a proof for that.

Comment: Disjoint implies commuting

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Two disjoint cycles commute.

You can prove this by observing that if $\tau=(a_1a_2\ldots a_k)$ and $\sigma=(b_1b_2\ldots b_s)$ are two disjoint cycles, then everything except $a_i$'s and $b_j$'s is fixed by $\tau \circ \sigma$ and $\sigma \circ \tau$. Now all that remains to be seen is what happens to $a_i$'s and $b_j$'s under these two compositions. $\sigma$ fixes all $a_i$'s and $\tau$ fixes all $b_j$'s.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ and $g$ are disjoint permutations, then

- $\langle f \rangle \cap \langle g \rangle = 1$
- $(fg)^n=f^n g^n$

Therefore, $(fg)^n=e$ implies $f^n = g^{-n} \in \langle f \rangle \cap \langle g \rangle = 1$ and so $f^n=e$ and $g^n=e$.